# Как исправить ошибку? TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python

```
def f(x, y):
    if x > y:
        return 0
    if x == y and x == 6:
        return 1
    if x < y:
        return f(x + 2, y) + f(x * 2, y) + f(x * 3, y)
print(f(2, 28))
```

Comment: Что вернёт функция если *x = y = 5*?

Comment: Наверное стоило сначала озвучит задание, нужно, чтобы траектория функции проходила через число 6, поэтому я и записал так

Comment: Так что вернёт функция если *x = y = 5*?

Comment: наверное вернет 5

Comment: "Наверное" не является приемлемым ответом. Это код, напишите тест, запустите его и получите ответ в котором вы будете уверены стопроцентно. (Извините, если я давлю. Вы, кажется, учитесь, я хочу чтобы вы учились правильно, а значит быстро.)

Comment: Оно вернуло единицу

Comment: У меня получился другой результат. Как вы тестировали?

Comment: Скорее всего я не правильно записал x = y = 5, как именно вы записали это в коде?

Comment: `print(f(5, 5))`. А как записали вы?

Comment: Я так и записал, но еще записал в четвертой строчке (не знаю почему) x == 5, поэтому и выводило 1. Теперь выводит None

Comment: Функция иногда возвращает `None`, который нельзя складывать с числами. Исправьте функцию так, чтобы она всегда, в своей области определения, возвращала число (соответствующее определению). Это лучший совет который вы можете получить, пока в вопросе нет полного описания задачи, которую вы решаете.

Answer (score 0):

Твоя функция возвращает None в случае, когда f(28, 28), потому что нет условия для обработки этого случая. Ты можешь исправить это, изменив условие if x == y and x == 6 на if x == y or x == 6, или добавив явное возвращение, например 0, если функция должна возвращать None.
Вот пример кода:

```
def f(x, y):
    if x > y:
        return 0
    if x == y and x == 6:
        return 1
    if x < y:
        return f(x + 2, y) + f(x * 2, y) + f(x * 3, y)
    return 0  # случай для x > y

print(f(2, 28))
```